# NSCFString valueForUndefinedKey this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key distinctUnionOfObjects

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

I have an array of strings with real class `_NSCFConstantString' and

```
[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

works as expected. But in case of array of strings with real class `_NSCFString' same keypath produces an error:

> '[<__NSCFString 0x14d9e4d0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not
>   key value coding-compliant for the key distinctUnionOfObjects.'

How can I use this keypath if I'm not constructing my array directly? And why this happening?

Full code:

```
    // demo array
    NSArray * a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"one" , @"two", nil];
    // remoteDictionariesArray - array of dictionaries from webservice obtained with AFNetworking : @[@{@"name":@"one", @"name":@"one", @"name":@"two"}]
    NSArray *namesArray = [remoteDictionariesArray valueForKeyPath:@"Name"];

    // works fine
    NSArray *unique = [a valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];

    // throw exception
    NSArray *unique1 = [namesArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

**Update:**

```
po remoteDictionariesArray
<__NSCFArray 0x14ea0990>(
{
    Name = "Name";
    ProductId = "d671fd2f-25cc-4b39-acea-7d2d2acb4f80";
},
{
    Name = "Name";
    ProductId = "49c691c7-9b38-488b-83c6-ba2d4a9a5e4c";
}
)

po namesArray
<__NSArrayI 0x14eab4d0>(
Name,
Name
)
```

NSArrayI elements are (__NSCFString *)

Comment: Can you show code examples for each case?

Comment: What does `remoteDictionariesArray` look like?  The error message indicates that `namesArray` actually contains a single string, not an array of strings.